# Plex installed on CentOS : 404 when navigating to URL

Tags: centos, plex

I installed Plex Media Server on CentOS by downloading the RPM file from [Plex's website](http://www.plexapp.com/getplex/).

When I navigate to Plex URL, I get a 404 not found:

[image]

When I go the base URL I get an XML file:

[image]

Linux reports that Plex is running:

[image]

Is there some setting on CentOS I need to adjust to make Plex's web pages show up in the browser?

Where could I look in the file system to see that the web pages exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just [found the solution](http://forums.plexapp.com/index.php/topic/59297-fedora-18-404-not-found-when-accessing-the-plex-manager-via-a-web-browser/):

In a terminal:

1. sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
2. change SELINUX=enforcing to SELINUX=disabled
3. reboot
4. go to plex url (127.0.0.1:32400/web) and it will load
5. sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
6. change SELINUX=disabled to SELINUX=enforcing
7. reboot

Plex works

Answer (score 1):

When I did my install Plex 404'd on me as well. I determined that in my case Plex was trying to use the system rsync binary instead of the rsync binary it comes bundled with.The forked rsync process runs in the `rsync_t` domain due to a transition rule that ships with CentOS 6 (The way plex ships currently it runs in the `initrc_t` domain). Processes confined by `rsync_t` are not allowed to write files in `var_lib_t` which causes an AVC denial that bubbles up as a 404 when Plex fails to initialize completely.

I've documented this issue in more detail on Plex's forums (thread linked below)

Thread: [Plex Media Server shows 404 Not Found](https://forums.plex.tv/index.php/topic/73260-plex-media-server-shows-404-not-found/?p=741845)

I'm currently writing a SELinux policy module that confines Plex processes to a Plex specific domain with a customized set of access controls. If you'd like to try it out please see the github project linked below.

GitHub: [SELinux policy module for Plex Media Server](https://github.com/devsr/plex-selinux)